# Bloblstore File API to GCS API

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I recently noticed that in the 1.8.1 App Engine release they changed the status from "experimental" to "deprecated" of the file-like API for Py 2.7 runtime Blobstore. Looking over the docs, it would seem they don't have a file-like context manager for Cloud File Storage. Has anyone migrated their Blobstorage to GCS API? Any tips and advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to add more to the answer? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

[Appengine-gcs-client](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/) allows you to use gcs from appengine in much the same was as old files api. I'm not sure why it's not made more prominent in the documentation.

Here's a snippet from the [demo](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/demo/main.py)

```
def create_file(self, filename):
     """Create a file.
     The retry_params specified in the open call will override the default
     retry params for this particular file handle.

     Args:
       filename: filename.
     """
     self.response.write('Creating file %s\n' % filename)

     write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
     gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                    'w',
                    content_type='text/plain',
                    options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                             'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
                    retry_params=write_retry_params)
     gcs_file.write('abcde\n')
     gcs_file.write('f'*1024*1024 + '\n')
     gcs_file.close()
     self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)
```

**Edit:**
It's in the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#about_the_google_cloud_storage_gcs_client_library

Comment: I did see that. My question was mostly because the missing context manager that abstracted the low level stuff away. For instance:
            with files.open(file_blob, 'a') as f:
                f.write(payload)
            files.finalize(file_blob)

Comment: You can still do things like this: with with gcs.open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('abcde\n')  (this is from the blobstore example, but writing to gcs: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/demo/blobstore.py)

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Thanks. That will make migration much easier.

Comment: Do I need to include a comparison or what else are you looking for in this answer?